# When I am developing an Android application, how to detect that the dolby is on or off?

Tags: android, audio, dolby, dolby-audio-api

When I am developing an Android application, how to detect that the dolby is on or off?

I want to know whether the cellphone turn on the dolby by program code and does Android provide this application interface?

Comment: What do you mean by "turn on the dolby"? Support for Dolby Digital decoding? Dolby Digital encoding? Dolby Atmos virtualizer effect...?

Answer (score 0):

There is an Android API from Dolby Developer which can be found at their website http://developer.dolby.com

You can make the following call DolbyAudioProcessing.getDolbyAudioProcessing() which will inform you if Dolby is available or not. If a "null" is returned, the Dolby Audio Processing isn't available.